# Odd poster - offensive answer content - what should I do?

Tags: discussion, support

Off of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137666#137666).

There is a [user](https://superuser.com/users/36110?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) who has now posted three questions I find offensive to the point where I edited them, and flagged for a mod.

At this point I'm beginning to wonder what he means by "do some moms" as mentioned in [two](https://superuser.com/posts/137666/revisions) of his [posts](https://superuser.com/posts/137662/revisions). His third (and first) [answer](https://superuser.com/posts/137663/revisions) was simply a crude comment to the user about him possibly getting his trackpad sticky after watching porn.

Now he has posted a [fourth answer](https://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137668#137668) while I was writing this up, and a [fifth](https://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137670#137670), [sixth](https://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137671#137671), and [seventh](https://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137673#137673) afterwards.

**What should be done in this case?**

Comment: Wow, a year-long suspension. Haven't seen that before.

Comment: Yep, and all the answers just got wiped out. That guy was a nut.

Comment: Well, a troll, really.  A kid.  Dime a dozen.

Comment: The guy [just](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137675#137675) [won't](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137677#137677) quit. Perhaps a temporary (12hr) IP ban?

Comment: And now he [actually posts something that looks like a good answer](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137678#137678).

Comment: [I've run out of flags](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137679#137679).

Comment: Add [another](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137680#137680) [two](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137679#137679) posts from him, though that account was just banned.

Comment: Should you be able to regenerate flags if previous flaggings have been accepted by a moderator?

Comment: He claims to be [unbannable](http://superuser.com/questions/137661/macbook-pro-13-inch-trackpad-makes-very-annoying-sounds-when-clicked/137688#137688). Anyone care to test?

Comment: @Andrew: Already writing up a question for meta about that.

Comment: Regardless of everything, you could have not [put an unnecessary  personal message to the troll](http://superuser.com/posts/137678/revisions). Also, seeing as you can edit posts, you should have removed the salutations on the question itself too.

Comment: If I see another reason to edit I will remove salutations while I'm doing that. Forgive me for being a little irked by 13+ answers I edited, flagged, and ultimately had removed.

Answer (score 4):

Hey may need to be warned, officially. It doesn't look like he gets *it* from your edits.

If the problems persist, [*I'll greate a GUI interface using Visual Basic - see if I can track an ipaddress.*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU)

Comment: I haven't had this much to edit in weeks. He's definitely **not** getting *it*.

Comment: this user doesn't need a warning, they need a spanking.

Comment: @quack Note that I suggested a warning *before* @Josh added references to the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th offenses :)

Comment: Make it eight or nine by now, I stopped keeping track. Spank away @quack.

Comment: @jon: ah.  yes, noted.  i didn't notice until there were quite a few.  (13 posts across 4 accounts.  so far.)

Comment: @quack Are you counting the meta posts too?

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the [Jon Skeet incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46512/).

Comment: What does this have to do with this? And why isn't this a comment?

Comment: you know why @voy

Comment: @voy: It is basically a similar thing - a user creating multiple accounts and posting nonsense...